# Left Join MYSQL Insert on three conditions

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to create an INSERT query whereby records in the table `holding` are inserted into table `price` where the following scenarios are met

```
  prod_name   prod_id   price       Outcome                          Reason                          
 ----------- --------- -------- --------- ------------------------------------------------------- 
  Prod B         2000   £10.00   Insert    New product exists                                     
  Prod A         1000   £8.00    Skip      Price for Prod A has not changed since last update  
  Prod A         1000   £7.00    Insert    Prod A has a new price                                 
  Prod A         1000   £10.00   Insert    Prod A has a new price and price previously existed
```

Based on the `holding` tables below.

```
  prod_name   prod_id   price    last_updated  
 ----------- --------- -------- -------------- 
  Prod B         2000   £10.00   2020-04-19    
  Prod A         1000   £8.00    2020-04-19    

  prod_name   prod_id   price    last_updated  
 ----------- --------- -------- --------------   
  Prod A         1000   £7.00    2020-04-20    

  prod_name   prod_id   price    last_updated 
 ----------- --------- -------- --------------   
  Prod A         1000   £7.00    2020-04-21
```

And the `price` table below

```
  prod_name   prod_id   price    last_updated  
 ----------- --------- -------- -------------- 
  Prod A         1000   £10.00   2020-04-17    
  Prod A         1000   £7.00    2020-04-18    
  Prod A         1000   £8.00    2020-04-19
```

When running the query below scenario 1,2 and 3 from the examples above work however example 4 does not work.

```
INSERT INTO price (prod_name, prod_id, price, last_updated)
SELECT t1.prod_name, t1.prod_id, t1.price, t1.last_updated FROM holding t1
LEFT JOIN price t2 ON t2.prod_id = t1.prod_id and t2.price = t1.price
WHERE t2.prod_id IS NULL and t2.price IS NULL;
```

The `holding` table consists of the same 4 columns as price and is generated on a daily basis and contains all of the products currently sold and their "on sale" price as of the day the `holding` table was populated

Any support to a newbie on stack overflow would be gratefully received.

Comment: The last inserted price for a is 7 so where did 10 come from?

Comment: Hi the 10 had come from a previous insert not included in the example. It was inserted as it met the first criteria in the examples above